# Cake Bake error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-bake

i am trying to use cakes baking console and when i use cake bake model all

i am getting the following error

[image]

Attendance Table Structure

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`attendences` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `dateTime` DATETIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: It appears your attendances table doesn't comply with CakePHP standards. Please post structure of your `attendances table`

Comment: `dateTime` column name should be `datetime` or `date_time` as per CakePHP conventions ( http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions ). Change it and retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than baking it all at once, do it table-by-table and model-controller-view separately. That way you'll be able to pin down the error.

Have you created any fixtures correctly? See http://book.cakephp.org/view/360/Creating-fixtures and check the syntax is correct, particularly in the array definitions.

Comment: i dont want any Fixtures. its doing automatically :(

Comment: Then I think you'll need to do it a bit less automatically. Try baking all the models, then the controllers etc.